# Concatenate two lists with determined values in prolog

Tags: prolog

So I just tried Prolog and here, I wanted to try making my own concatenate function, that combines two lists (First List first with X elements, then Second List with Y elements). I am trying this using recursive, but after I tried to do some queries, it gives a no.
Here is my code.

```
/* These two functions are already correct, I checked it and it cannot be changed anymore */

push(Element,[], Result) :- Result = [Element], !.
push(Element,Queue,Result) :- [Head|Tail] = Queue, push(Element, Tail, Tail2), Result = [Head|Tail2].

pop(Queue,Result) :- [_|Tail] = Queue, Result = Tail.

/* concatenate */
concatenate(_,_,0,0,Result) :- Result = [], !.
concatenate(FList,SList,0,Y,Result) :- pop(SList,B), push(B,Result,Result), [_|Tail] = SList, Z is Y-1, concatenate(FList,Tail,0,Z,Result).
concatenate(FList,SList,X,Y,Result) :- pop(FList,A), push(A,Result,Result), [_|Tail] = FList, Z1 is X-1, concatenate(Tail,SList,Z1,Y,Result).

/* Query */
| ?- concatenate([1,2,3],[2,3,4],1,2,R).
no
```

I think that the push part here is the one that gives wrong results, but maybe there are also other parts.
Can anyone guide or help me to solve this matter?

Comment: What's wrong with "append([a,b],[1,2],L)." which gives L=[a,b,1,2] ? It combines first list first until it is empty then second list.

Comment: Hi, Peter. I am trying to not use the pre-defined functions in prolog just for the sake of practicing the logic behind the function itself.

Comment: Also, I edited some parts in the question that may seems ambiguous. Hope that it is clear now.

Comment: What are arguments3 and 4 doing?

Comment: Yes, that's the part I edited. So, from First List we take X (args3) elements and push it into the results. After that, we take Y (args4) elements from the Second List and push it into the results.

Comment: If you want to practice, this is not the way. You are using your old habits in a new/different paradigm. That is a bad way to start Prolog.

Comment: I guess that is true, but I am just practicing to follow the curriculum of my college so nothing much I can do, sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

````
pop(Queue,Result) :- [_|Tail] = Queue, Result = Tail.

push(Element,[], Result) :- Result = [Element], !.
push(Element,Queue,Result) :- [Head|Tail] = Queue, push(Element, Tail, Tail2), Result = [Head|Tail2].

concatenate(_,_,0,0,Result) :- Result = [], !.

concatenate(FList,SList,0,Y,Result) :- [Head|Tail] = SList, Z is Y-1, concatenate(FList,Tail,0,Z,Result2), Result = [Head|Result2], !.
concatenate(FList,SList,X,Y,Result) :-  [Head|Tail] = FList, Z1 is X-1, concatenate(Tail,SList,Z1,Y,Result2), Result = [Head|Result2].```
````